# Unable to run jmeter distributed test with ubuntu as node

Tags: java, linux, jmeter

Im trying to run jmeter test in distributed mode, following to official documentation:
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html

client - windows 7
server - ubuntu 20

But I have next error:

```
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using D:\r.jmx
Configuring remote engine: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Starting distributed test with remote engines: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] @ Tue Apr 27 23
:29:27 EEST 2021 (1619555367546)
Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling argume
nts; nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
Remote engines have been started:[]
The following remote engines have not started:[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 44
45
```

How I can fix it or how to determine, what exactly I should fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the [log files](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) on both master and slave, most probably they contain the cause of the error or at least a cloue
2. Looking into the output my expectation is that there is something preventing network communication between the machines, make sure that:

   - machines can "see" each other, i.e. they are on the same [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) and you reach from master to slave and vice versa using ping/telnet commands
   - the following ports are open in the operating systems [firewalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)):

     - `1099` or if you changed `server_port` property value this new port
     - the port you define as `server.rmi.localport`
     - the port(s) you define as  `client.rmi.localport`

You can check out [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker) article which provides comprehensive explanation of the network setup for the distributed more of running a JMeter test

Comment: I will be very happy if you answer for one more question. Is it even possible to start distributed testing, where client is my local pc, and servers are somewhere in cloud?

Comment: As long as there is a bi-directional connectivity it is possible. "To start" should be pretty easy, a more tricky point is to collect results and you need to either have a static IP address or set up some form of VPN so cloud hosts could "see" your on-premise machine